# proof of one matrix rank inequality

Tags: linear-algebra

I forgot how to prove the following inequality. Could anybody help?

Let $A, B, C$ be matrices of appropriate dimensions:
$$rank\left( \left[\begin{array}{rr}
A & 0\\
C & B
\end{array}\right]\right)\ge rank\left( \left[\begin{array}{rr}
A & 0\\
0 & B
\end{array}\right]\right).$$

Comment: What does rank-nullity imply?

Comment: @ehsanmo: does rank-nullity imply this directly? If so, please post an answer with such reasoning. I do not see this argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you apply the elementary row operations that bring the right-hand matrix into row echelon form to both matrices, the result is the same on both sides except in the $C$ block, which may have additional non-zero entries. Then all rows that are linearly independent on the right-hand side are also linearly independent on the left-hand side, and possibly more.

Comment: I think it would just be somewhat difficult to write down the detailed proof. I guess we should separately bring $A$ and $B$ to row echelon form, rather than bringing the whole matrix to its row echelon form, to give the argument, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \in M_{p\times q}(\mathbb K)$, $C \in M_{(n-p)\times q}(\mathbb K)$ and $B \in M_{(n-p)\times (n-q)}(\mathbb K)$. We may decompose $\mathbb K^n=\mathbb K^p\times 0 \oplus 0 \times \mathbb K^(n-p)$ and consider
$$\{a_1,\dots,a_q\} \subset \mathbb K^p\times 0$$
the set of columms of $A$,
$$\{b_1,\dots,b_q\} \subset 0 \times \mathbb K^{n-p}$$
the set of columms of $B$  and
$$\{c_1,\dots,c_q\} \subset 0 \times \mathbb K^{n-p}$$
the set of columms of $C$.

So, it suffices to show that given an LI subset
$$\{a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_s},b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_r}\}$$
of
$$\{a_1,\dots,a_q,b_1,\dots,b_{n-q}\}$$
we have that
$$\{a_{i_1}+c_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_s}+c_{i_s},b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_r}\}$$
is a LI subset of
$$\{a_1+c_1,\dots,a_q+c_q,b_1,\dots,b_{n-q}\}.$$
In fact, if
$$\alpha_{i_1}(a_{i_1}+c_{i_1})+\dots+\alpha_{i_s}(a_{i_s}+c_{i_s})+\beta_{j_1}b_{j_1},\dots,\beta_{j_r}b_{j_r} = 0$$
for some $\alpha$s and $\beta$s \in $\mathbb K$, we must have that
$$\mathbb K^p \times 0 \ni \alpha_{i_1}a_{i_1} +\dots+\alpha_{i_s}a_{i_s} = 0$$
and
$$0 \times \mathbb K^{n-p} \ni \alpha_{i_1}c_{i_1}+\dots+\alpha_{i_s}c_{i_s}+\beta_{j_1}b_{j_1},\dots,\beta_{j_r}b_{j_r} = 0.$$
By the linear independence of
$$\{a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_s}\} \subset \{a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_s},b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_r}\}$$
we must have that
$$\alpha_{i_1}=\dots=\alpha_{i_s}=0$$
and, hence,
$$\beta_{j_1}b_{j_1}+\dots+\beta_{j_r}b_{j_r} = 0.$$
Again,
$$\{b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_r}\}\subset \{a_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_s},b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_r}\}$$
implies that
$$\beta_{j_1}=\dots=\beta_{j_r}=0.$$
Therefore, we conclude that
$$\{a_{i_1}+c_{i_1},\dots,a_{i_s}+c_{i_s},b_{j_1},\dots,b_{j_r}\}$$
is a LI set.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c'_1,..., c'_n$ be the columns of

$$\left( \left[\begin{array}{rr}
A & 0\\
C & B
\end{array}\right]\right)$$

and $c_1,..., c_n$ be the colums of

$$\left( \left[\begin{array}{rr}
A & 0\\
0 & B
\end{array}\right]\right)$$

If $c_{i_1},..., c_{i_j}$ are linearly independent and

$$k_1c'_{i_1}+...+ k_jc'_{i_j} =0 \,.$$

then, it follows immediately by writing explicitely the columns that $k_1=..=k_j=0$.

Hence if we pick a basis in the column  space of $\left( \left[\begin{array}{rr}
A & 0\\
0 & B
\end{array}\right]\right)$, the correcponding colums are linearly independent in $\left( \left[\begin{array}{rr}
A & 0\\
C & B
\end{array}\right]\right)$, which proves the inequality.